# Find a norm on $\Bbb{R}^2$ for which $\|(0, 1)\| = 1 = \|(1, 0)\|$ and for which $\|(1, 1)\| = 0.0001$.

Tags: real-analysis, normed-spaces

Find a norm on $\Bbb{R}^2$ for which $\|(0, 1)\| = 1 = \|(1, 0)\|$ and for which $\|(1, 1)\| = 0.0001$.  Show that your answer works.

I know obviously that the $\Bbb{R}^2$ norm is the Euclidean norm, but I am unsure on how to do the actual question. Any help much appreciated!

Comment: The euclidean norm does not have the desired property, since the euclidean norm of $(1,1)$ is $\sqrt 2$.  You'll need to find a new norm that does have the desired property.

Comment: As an addition to lulu's comment: $p$-norms do not work in general. To get $\|(1,1)\|_{p}=10^{-4}$, we need $2^{1/p}=10^{-4}$. This equation has no solutions for $p\geq1$.

Comment: Find an ellipse, centered at the origin, and passing through the three points $(1,0), (0,1), (10000, 10000)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd try a norm based on a positive definite symmetric matrix:
$$\|(x,y)\|^2=\pmatrix{x&y}A\pmatrix{x\\y}$$
defines a norm if the matrix $A$ is positive definite. To get $\|(1,0)\|=\|(0,1)\|=1$ one needs
$$A=\pmatrix{1&b\\b&1}$$
and this is positive definite if $b^2<1$. You want $\|(1,1)\|^2=10^{-8}$. But
$$\|(1,1)\|^2=2+2b.$$
Does the solution of $2+2b=10^{-8}$ for $b$ also satisfy $b^2<1$?

Comment: Thanks. I understand the working,  but the whole idea of norms is confusing me. I know the conditions on which a function can be considered a norm. I know the 1 norm, infinity norm and the 2 norm etc, but anything other than that confuses me as to where it's come from

Comment: This example is really just an $\ell^2$ norm adjusted by a linear transformation. It is $\|Bu\|_2$ where  $B$ is a matrix square root of $A$.

Comment: So what would I do if I wanted to use  $||(a, b)|| = A|a + b| + B|a − b|$ in my answer, instead of a matrix?

Comment: You could work out $A$ and $B$. If they are both positive, you have a norm. @AnoUser1

Comment: Ok, so the actual norm part is $A|a+b| + B|a-b|$ ? And to show it works, I simply sub in the numbers in the conditions stated?

Answer (score 2):

Consider the norm

$$\|(x,y)\| := 0.00005|x|+0.00005|y| + 0.99995 |x-y|$$

Then $$\|(1,0)\| = \|(0,1)\| = 0.00005+0.99995 = 1$$
and $$\|(1,1)\| = 0.00005 + 0.00005 = 0.0001.$$

Answer (score 2):

Any convex set $D$ with an open interior symmetrical about the origin defines a norm for which it is the unit disk. The norm of any vector is the ratio of the (Euclidean) distance to the origin over the distance along that ray to the boundary of $D$.

Now draw a long skinny ellipse with major axis the line $y=x$ passing through the points $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$. If it's long enough the new distance to $(1,1)$ can be as small as you like.

[maybe I will come back later and insert a picture, or someone can edit to do that]